# android getting error while displaying image from url

Tags: android, imageview

When i'm displaying image from url with using below code, application is taking too much time to load images from server. Application is hanging up if we have 8-10 images to load.

```
Bitmap mbmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new java.net.URL("urlname").openStream());
Imageview_ref.setImageBitmap(mbmp);
```

and getting this in **Logcat**

```
09-15 11:34:14.265: ERROR/Cursor(14443): Finalizing a Cursor that has not been deactivated or closed. database = /data/data/com.UserLogin/databases/sample.db, table = null, query = SELECT LocationName , LocationImage FROM Locationlist
09-15 11:34:14.265: ERROR/Cursor(14443): android.database.sqlite.DatabaseObjectNotClosedException: Application did not close the cursor or database object that was opened here
09-15 11:34:14.265: ERROR/Cursor(14443):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor.<init>(SQLiteCursor.java:210)
09-15 11:34:14.265: ERROR/Cursor(14443):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.query(SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.java:53)
09-15 11:34:14.265: ERROR/Cursor(14443):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1345)
09-15 11:34:14.265: ERROR/Cursor(14443):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQuery(SQLiteDatabase.java:1315)
09-15 11:34:14.265: ERROR/Cursor(14443):     at com.UserLogin.FindPlaces.getallLocs(FindPlaces.java:134)
09-15 11:34:14.265: ERROR/Cursor(14443):     at com.UserLogin.FindPlaces.onCreate(FindPlaces.java:37)
09-15 11:34:14.265: ERROR/Cursor(14443):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
09-15 11:34:14.265: ERROR/Cursor(14443):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
09-15 11:34:14.265: ERROR/Cursor(14443):     at android.app.ActivityThread.startActivityNow(ActivityThread.java:2503)
09-15 11:34:14.265: ERROR/Cursor(14443):     at android.app.LocalActivityManager.moveToState(LocalActivityManager.java:127)
09-15 11:34:14.265: ERROR/Cursor(14443):     at android.app.LocalActivityManager.startActivity(LocalActivityManager.java:339)
09-15 11:34:14.265: ERROR/Cursor(14443):     at android.widget.TabHost$IntentContentStrategy.getContentView(TabHost.java:651)
09-15 11:34:14.265: ERROR/Cursor(14443):     at android.widget.TabHost.setCurrentTab(TabHost.java:323)
09-15 11:34:14.265: ERROR/Cursor(14443):     at android.widget.TabHost$2.onTabSelectionChanged(TabHost.java:129)
09-15 11:34:14.265: ERROR/Cursor(14443):     at android.widget.TabWidget$TabClickListener.onClick(TabWidget.java:453)
09-15 11:34:14.265: ERROR/Cursor(14443):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2408)
09-15 11:34:14.265: ERROR/Cursor(14443):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:8816)
09-15 11:34:14.265: ERROR/Cursor(14443):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
09-15 11:34:14.265: ERROR/Cursor(14443):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
09-15 11:34:14.265: ERROR/Cursor(14443):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
09-15 11:34:14.265: ERROR/Cursor(14443):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
09-15 11:34:14.265: ERROR/Cursor(14443):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-15 11:34:14.265: ERROR/Cursor(14443):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
09-15 11:34:14.265: ERROR/Cursor(14443):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
09-15 11:34:14.265: ERROR/Cursor(14443):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
09-15 11:34:14.265: ERROR/Cursor(14443):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

with this logcat error message i'm still getting output.

this is my updated code view..

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            View v = convertView;
            if(v == null){
                LayoutInflater vl = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                v = vl.inflate(R.layout.placeslist, null);
            }
            Fields o = results.get(position);

            if (o != null) {
                TextView iv = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.toptext);
                ImageView tv_Image = (ImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.Locimage);

                iv.setText(o.getLocationName());                            

                try {
                    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream((InputStream) new URL(o.getLocationImage()).getContent());
                    tv_Image.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }


            }
            return v;
        }       
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this ::

```
            try {
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream((InputStream) new URL(
                "http://xyz.com/a/f/a.png")
                .getContent());
        tran_btn_skip.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
```

Make sure you have to give permission of Internet

Comment: thanks Nik. we can use this piece of code for all type of images right?, and are you sure with this code image will load from server?

Comment: Nic.. its working fine, but for one image. i'm getting this message in logcat and image is not displaying..::: 09-15 12:28:47.886: DEBUG/skia(26484): --- decoder->decode returned false
:::

Comment: print  `Fields o` in logcat and tell me what you get

Comment: url is coming fine but the image is not displaying in view

Comment: so you cant show image in it please try device it get successfully

Answer (score 3):

logcat shows that you are not closing your **cursor** and **database**

**onDestroy()** method of your activity, add this

```
try{
   cursor.close();
   db.close(); 
}catch(exception e)
{}
```

Comment: shall i close it by overriding application onDestroy method. How to close cursor.